# Firebase 3.0 createUserWithEmailAndPassword() error handling

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Before, with Firebase 2.x, in order to add a New User we just had to call `createUser()` on a Firebase reference, pass in the email, password and a `ValueResultHandler`.

Two callbacks were implemented with that `ValueResultHandler`:

- `onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {}`
- `onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}`

In `onError`, it was easy to grab the `firebaseError` to handle errors. 
Like:

```
if (firebaseError.getCode() == FirebaseError.EMAIL_TAKEN) {}
```

However now with the Firebase SDK 3.0, things have changed as it is indicated on the [Documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account).

But how do we do error handling then? For example on that case with an email already taken? Thanks.

Comment: The link you shared is for Authenticating the user, but for creating user you can still use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method

Comment: The Documentation page in the Link has both: Sign In and Create an Account

Comment: ok, then for getting exception you can use `task.getException()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add new methods when you call createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
You should add the method addOnFailureListener. This is a code example:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
            addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_error_auth,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   // Here you get the error type
                   Log.d(TAG + " - On Failure", e.getMessage());
            }
    });
```